# How to set the font of a Unicode control?

Tags: c, winapi

To set the font of an ANSI control, I create an `HFONT` object and send it (through `SendMessage()`) to the control. This is how I crate the `HFONT` object:

```
HFONT hFont = CreateFont(13, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "Tahoma");
```

I believe that all of the parameters are the same for a Unicode control except for the 9th parameter. For an ANSI control, this parameter is `ANSI_CHARSET`, but what should it be for a Unicode control?

Comment: @moffeltje - `CreateFont()` is applicable in C as well as in C++, so yes, this appears to be related to C.

Comment: Character sets have been irrelevant for the past 2 decades, just use DEFAULT_CHARSET.

Comment: @Hans Passant Should I use `DEFAULT_CHARSET` for both an ANSI control and a Unicode control?

Comment: Stop using the ANSI API, and pass `DEFAULT_CHARSET`.

Comment: @David Heffernan I am not using the ANSI API, but I would like to know what value I should pass for this parameter in case I was.

Comment: You are using the ANSI API. If you were using the Unicode API you'd be passing `L"Tahoma"`.

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes, you are right. I mean in my actual project I am using Unicode.

Comment: All we have to go on is the code in your question. Which calls `CreateFontA`.

Comment: @David Heffernan I thought I posted a Unicode example. Anyway, my question was if I should use `DEFAULT_CHARSET` for an ANSI control also.

Comment: You are using the ANSI API. Pass `DEFAULT_CHARSET` always.

Comment: @David Heffernan Just to be sure, I should pass `DEFAULT_CHARSET` for both an ANSI control and a Unicode control?

Comment: Yes. But why are you even calling `CreateWindowExA` in the first place? And why do you think you need to create fonts differently for ANSI controls.

Comment: @David Heffernan I said in my question that this code is used to set the font of an ANSI control (and so I posted an ANSI function example), then I asked: what should I pass for this parameter to set the font of a Unicode control. I thought that I need to create fonts differently for ANSI controls because this parameter is confusing, and it has an `ANSI_CHARSET` value, and so I thought that if this value is for an ANSI control, then there could be another value for a Unicode control (it feels weird passing a value that is named `ANSI_*` to a Unicode control!).

Comment: I still can't understand why you are creating ANSI controls. It's 2015!

Comment: @David Heffernan I am not creating ANSI controls, I just found this example from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221411/how-can-i-specify-a-font-for-a-window-created-through-createwindow, and this example was intended for an ANSI control. And so I posted it to say that this is how to set the font of an ANSI control, and then I asked what should I use for a Unicode control.

Comment: I think you need to find a better tutorial than that answer from a low rep user.

Comment: @David Heffernan All of the answers for that question says the same thing, this user just gave an example, and it has 3 up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

***[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688113.aspx)*** discusses Unicode and how to implement code using it.  The very first requirements are to #define UNICODE so that the generic Windows APIs will resolve to the UNICODE versions.
***In your example***, you make the statement:
*I believe that all of the parameters are the same for a Unicode control except for the 9th parameter*.
***Not correct*** as the last parameter must be a Unicode string.

In your code example, do the following:

```
#define UNICODE  //place in project visible .h file
```

Change:

```
HFONT hFont = CreateFont(13, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, "Tahoma");
```

To:

```
HFONT hFont = CreateFont(13, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, L"Tahoma");
                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

From ***[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** Here is the predefined list for use in the function `CreateFont()`(pay attention to DEFAULT_CHARSET):

***This*** site may be helpful: ***[Programming with Unicode](http://unicodebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/programming_languages.html)***

Comment: I asked this question because I did not know what value I should pick for a Unicode control.

Comment: Isn't everything that isn't the first (ANSI), Unicode?

Comment: DEFAULT_CHARSET (further down in list) is set to a value based on the current system locale. For example, when the system locale is English (United States), it is set as ANSI_CHARSET.  If it is set to another nationality, it will accomodate.  Have you tried that?  ***[Here is a conversation](http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.international.narkive.com/5Tt3tPkw/createfont-for-unicode)*** that may help.

Comment: @ryyker It looks a little as though you've answered the question in spite of not knowing the answer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The real problem here is that no one, including the asker has discovered the ***real*** question yet.  If they had, the likelihood of an accurate answer would be greatly increased.  As it is, given the amorphis condition of the facts presented, I gave it my best shot.

Comment: The asker wants to know which charset to use. Your answer is "pick one". The asker asked which one. Do you have an answer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - A little reading in the link I provided, I felt, would be sufficient to find the right answer.  If that is indeed the only thing OP is asking, the link included all the details necessary to draw a conclusion, including the following:  ***DEFAULT_CHARSET is set to a value based on the current system locale...***, My original focus, whether right or wrong, was to address usage of  `CreateFont()` (or more precisely `CreateFontW()` ), as it applies to Unicode.  My intent was to help guide, not to solve.  (I did not have too much time yesterday)

Comment: CreateFontA or CreateFontW come to the same here since Tahoma is spelled with ASCII characters. I don't think you are on top of this at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I do not have perfect knowledge on this topic.  But my latest edits may at least contribute.  I would like to see your thoughts expressed in an answer, if you would.  Thanks.

Comment: @user4582812 - See my latest edit.  Hope it helps.  I am still monitoring, so please ask questions if not clear.

Comment: You aren't addressing any of the points I raised. Never mind.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - DEFAULT_CHARSET, L"Tahoma".  What other point(s) specifically did you raise?

Comment: My comments are clear enough. There's no point in me continuing unless you actively wish to understand what I am saying.