# How can I change the font_style or font_size of the default window?

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to change the font for a window.

[image]

Comment: [`WM_SETFONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-setfont), see [How can I specify a font for a window created through CreateWindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221411/)

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Did you read the links?  Note, this sets the font for the *window*. If you are trying to set the font for a *menu*, the only way to do that is to [draw the menu items yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-menus#creating-owner-drawn-menu-items).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Creating Owner-Drawn Menu Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-menus#creating-owner-drawn-menu-items) as @RemyLebeau said, I complete a sample with a little change compared with the document code.

[image] 
Code:

```
/********************/
#define CITEMS 4
#define REGULAR 0
#define BOLD 1
#define ITALIC 2
#define ULINE 3

HFONT GetAFont(int fnFont)
{
    static LOGFONT lf;  // structure for font information  

    // Get a handle to the ANSI fixed-pitch font, and copy 
    // information about the font to a LOGFONT structure. 

    GetObject(GetStockObject(ANSI_FIXED_FONT), sizeof(LOGFONT),
        &lf);

    // Set the font attributes, as appropriate.  

    if (fnFont == BOLD)
        lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;
    else
        lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;

    lf.lfItalic = (fnFont == ITALIC);
    lf.lfItalic = (fnFont == ULINE);

    // Create the font, and then return its handle.  

    return CreateFont(lf.lfHeight, lf.lfWidth,
        lf.lfEscapement, lf.lfOrientation, lf.lfWeight,
        lf.lfItalic, lf.lfUnderline, lf.lfStrikeOut, lf.lfCharSet,
        lf.lfOutPrecision, lf.lfClipPrecision, lf.lfQuality,
        lf.lfPitchAndFamily, lf.lfFaceName);
}

LRESULT APIENTRY MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    typedef struct _MYITEM
    {
        HFONT hfont;
        LPSTR psz;
    } MYITEM;             // structure for item font and string  

    MYITEM* pmyitem;      // pointer to item's font and string        
    static MYITEM myitem[CITEMS];   // array of MYITEMS               
    static HMENU hmenu;             // handle to main menu            
    static COLORREF crSelText;  // text color of selected item        
    static COLORREF crSelBkgnd; // background color of selected item  
    COLORREF crText;            // text color of unselected item      
    COLORREF crBkgnd;           // background color unselected item   
    LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpmis;  // pointer to item of data             
    LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis;     // pointer to item drawing data        
    HDC hdc;                    // handle to screen DC                
    SIZE size;                  // menu-item text extents             
    WORD wCheckX;               // check-mark width                   
    int nTextX;                 // width of menu item                 
    int nTextY;                 // height of menu item                
    int i;                      // loop counter                       
    HFONT hfontOld;             // handle to old font                 
    BOOL fSelected = FALSE;     // menu-item selection flag
    size_t length = 0;
    size_t* pcch = &length;
    HRESULT hResult;
    HMENU hCharacterMenu;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

        // Modify the Regular, Bold, Italic, and Underline 
        // menu items to make them owner-drawn items. Associate 
        // a MYITEM structure with each item to contain the 
        // string for and font handle to each item. 

        hmenu = GetMenu(hwnd);
        ModifyMenu(hmenu, IDM_REGULAR, MF_BYCOMMAND |
            MF_CHECKED | MF_OWNERDRAW, IDM_REGULAR,
            (LPTSTR)&myitem[REGULAR]);
        ModifyMenu(hmenu, IDM_BOLD, MF_BYCOMMAND |
            MF_OWNERDRAW, IDM_BOLD, (LPTSTR)&myitem[BOLD]);
        ModifyMenu(hmenu, IDM_ITALIC, MF_BYCOMMAND |
            MF_OWNERDRAW, IDM_ITALIC,
            (LPTSTR)&myitem[ITALIC]);
        ModifyMenu(hmenu, IDM_ULINE, MF_BYCOMMAND |
            MF_OWNERDRAW, IDM_ULINE, (LPTSTR)&myitem[ULINE]);

        /********/
        //hCharacterMenu = GetSubMenu(hmenu,1);
        ModifyMenu(hmenu, 1, MF_BYPOSITION |
            MF_OWNERDRAW, 0,
            (LPTSTR)&myitem[BOLD]);
        /********/

        // Retrieve each item's font handle and copy it into 
        // the hfont member of each item's MYITEM structure. 
        // Also, copy each item's string into the structures. 

        myitem[REGULAR].hfont = GetAFont(REGULAR);
        myitem[REGULAR].psz = (char*)"Regular";
        myitem[BOLD].hfont = GetAFont(BOLD);
        myitem[BOLD].psz = (char*)"Bold";
        myitem[ITALIC].hfont = GetAFont(ITALIC);
        myitem[ITALIC].psz = (char*)"Italic";
        myitem[ULINE].hfont = GetAFont(ULINE);
        myitem[ULINE].psz = (char*)"Underline";

        // Retrieve the text and background colors of the 
        // selected menu text. 

        crSelText = GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT);
        crSelBkgnd = GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT);

        return 0;

    case WM_MEASUREITEM:

        // Retrieve a device context for the main window.  

        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

        // Retrieve pointers to the menu item's 
        // MEASUREITEMSTRUCT structure and MYITEM structure. 

        lpmis = (LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
        pmyitem = (MYITEM*)lpmis->itemData;

        // Select the font associated with the item into 
        // the main window's device context. 

        hfontOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(hdc, pmyitem->hfont);

        // Retrieve the width and height of the item's string, 
        // and then copy the width and height into the 
        // MEASUREITEMSTRUCT structure's itemWidth and 
        // itemHeight members.

        hResult = StringCchLength(pmyitem->psz, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH, pcch);
        if (FAILED(hResult))
        {
            // Add code to fail as securely as possible.
            return NULL;
        }

        GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, pmyitem->psz,
            *pcch, &size);
        lpmis->itemWidth = size.cx;
        lpmis->itemHeight = size.cy;

        // Select the old font back into the device context, 
        // and then release the device context. 

        SelectObject(hdc, hfontOld);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        return TRUE;

        break;

    case WM_DRAWITEM:

        // Get pointers to the menu item's DRAWITEMSTRUCT 
        // structure and MYITEM structure. 

        lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
        pmyitem = (MYITEM*)lpdis->itemData;

        // If the user has selected the item, use the selected 
        // text and background colors to display the item. 

        if (lpdis->itemState & ODS_SELECTED)
        {
            crText = SetTextColor(lpdis->hDC, crSelText);
            crBkgnd = SetBkColor(lpdis->hDC, crSelBkgnd);
            fSelected = TRUE;
        }

        // Remember to leave space in the menu item for the 
        // check-mark bitmap. Retrieve the width of the bitmap 
        // and add it to the width of the menu item. 

        wCheckX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMENUCHECK);
        nTextX = wCheckX + lpdis->rcItem.left;
        nTextY = lpdis->rcItem.top;

        // Select the font associated with the item into the 
        // item's device context, and then draw the string. 

        hfontOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(lpdis->hDC, pmyitem->hfont);

        hResult = StringCchLength(pmyitem->psz, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH, pcch);
        if (FAILED(hResult))
        {
            // Add code to fail as securely as possible.
            return NULL;
        }

        ExtTextOut(lpdis->hDC, nTextX, nTextY, ETO_OPAQUE,
            &lpdis->rcItem, pmyitem->psz,
            *pcch, NULL);

        // Select the previous font back into the device 
        // context. 

        SelectObject(lpdis->hDC, hfontOld);

        // Return the text and background colors to their 
        // normal state (not selected). 

        if (fSelected)
        {
            SetTextColor(lpdis->hDC, crText);
            SetBkColor(lpdis->hDC, crBkgnd);
        }

        return TRUE;

        // Process other messages.  

    case WM_DESTROY:

        // Destroy the menu items' font handles.  

        for (i = 0; i < CITEMS; i++)
            DeleteObject(myitem[i].hfont);

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return NULL;
}
/********************/
```